# Get Visual Studio (2013 Community) unit test execution messages

Tags: unit-tests, c#, visualstudio, test-report

[image: Test error message screenshot]

Hi, I'm trying to make a "nice" test execution report and get the following elements:

1. Message
2. StackTrace
3. Elapsed time

Test name and Test Outcome are easily taken as TestContext parameters, for output I'm using `Console.SetOut(StreamWriter)`. List of attachments are also known (because they are created during report generated).

I'd try to use:

- `Console.SetError` (returns null)
- `System.Envoirement.StackTrace` (return some another message),
- `System.Diagnostic.StackTrace`

Comment: Sure you want to build your own test-reports? Maybe some like this http://trx2html.codeplex.com/ will give you head start.

Comment: Hi @NielsvanReijmersdal, thanks you for answer
No, it is not a mandatory to create my own report, but unfortunately (possible, I looked in wrong place) I couldn't find where VS 2013 Community edition create/save trx files

Comment: I am not really into the VS IDE, but I run my teams unit-test from the command-line with vstest.console.exe . This generates a trx file if you add /logger:trx Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bhuvaneshwari/archive/2012/06/16/vstest-console-exe-commandline-test-runner.aspx

Comment: Thanks again! Now I know another way to run unit test:) Unfortunately, when I run vstest.console.exe tests.dll all them are failed. After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698409/how-to-run-selenium-c-sharp-test-in-command-prompt (similar topic) I still have no answer (so, I try to run Webdriver Selenium tests, written as VS unit test; when they run in VS - all OK)